# Can mod_headers change headers generated by uWSGI?

Tags: apache, uwsgi, mod-headers

I have a uWSGI service running behing an apache front-end. The part of my apache conf handling that lools like:

```
     <Location /myapp>
         SetHandler uwsgi-handler
         uWSGISocket /var/run/uwsgi/myapp.sock
         Allow from all
    </Location>
```

and I'd like to add a custom header to the responses of my app. I know I can do that by adding some code in the app, but I would prefer doing it with `mod_headers`, by adding the following line in the `Location` directive

```
         Header set Custom-Header "hello world"
```

It does not seem to work, although [mod_headers documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) states

> This directive can replace, merge or remove HTTP response headers.
>   The header is modified just after the content handler and output filters are run,
>   *allowing outgoing headers to be modified*.

What do I do wrong, or understand wrong?

Comment: Could it be something specific with ``mod_uswgi``? I admit I didn't take time to test with other content handlers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs mod_uwsgi is very raw and uses the 'assbackwards' mode, unless you enable the CGI mode. This mode (assbackwards) gives superior performance but breaks basically all of the filters. You should use mod_proxy_uwsgi (fully apache-friendly) or let uWSGI do the hard work for you using the internal routing:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/InternalRouting.html

(or the --add-header more invasive option)

Comment: So I was interpreting the doc correctly, just not reading the right doc :) Thanks for the answer and the alternative solution.